# HTML5 Video Replay Button Hide at Start

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-video

I have a bug with my HTML5 Video player where the replay button shows at the start. I want to show the play button and not the replay. The replay button seems to be functioning properly, just doesn't hide at start.

CSS

```
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 680px;
}

.video-wrapper > video {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide iOS Play Button */
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
    display: none!important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}


.playButton {
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 8px solid #fff !important;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.95;
  transition: opacity 400ms;
}

.playButton:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 25px 0 25px 50px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.replayButton {
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 8px solid #fff !important;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.95;
  transition: opacity 150ms;
}

.replayButton:before {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 18px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-color: transparent white white white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.replayButton:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 45px 22px 22px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="video-wrapper">
    <video id="bVideo">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <div id="playButton" class="playButton" onclick="playPause()"></div>
    <div class="replayButton" id="replayButton" onclick="playPause()"></div>
  </div>
```

Script

```
var bunnyVideo = document.getElementById("bVideo");
var el = document.getElementById("playButton");
var replay = document.getElementById("replayButton");
function playPause() {
  if (bunnyVideo.paused) 
  {
    bunnyVideo.play();
    el.className = "";
    replay.className = "";
  } 
  else 
  {
    bunnyVideo.pause();
    el.className = "playButton";
    replay.className = "";
  }
}

function playPauseControls() {
  if (!bunnyVideo.paused) {
    el.className ="";
    replay.className = "";
  } else {
     el.className = "playButton";
     replay.className = "";
  }
}

function videoEnd() {
  replay.className = "replayButton";
  el.className = "";
  bunnyVideo.setAttribute("controls","controls");
}

function showControls(){
  bunnyVideo.setAttribute("controls","controls");
}
function hideControls(){
  bunnyVideo.removeAttribute("controls","controls");
}
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("play", playPauseControls, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("pause", playPauseControls, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("mouseover", showControls, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("mouseout", hideControls, false);
playButton.addEventListener("mouseover", showControls, false);
replay.addEventListener("mouseover", showControls, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("ended", videoEnd, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/prpzv8wh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the div to invisible when you start your javascript:

```
var replay = document.getElementById("replayButton");
replay.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Then in the replay call back set it to visible:

```
function videoEnd() {
  replay.className = "replayButton";
  replay.style.visibility = "visible";
  el.className = "";
  bunnyVideo.setAttribute("controls","controls");
}
```